# Keep max 20 items in S3 using cloud formations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating an S3Bucket using cloud formations. I want to keep max 20 items in S3. If the 21th appears, the oldest one can be deleted from the bucket.
How can I configure this in S3?

I found some info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html). But this only tells me how to keep my items a certain timeframe instead of amount?

```
xxxS3Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain 
  Properties: 
    AccessControl: Private 
    BucketName: !Join [ "-", [!Ref ProjectName, "app", !Ref Environment ] ]
    LifecycleConfiguration
      Rules:
        -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put an s3 event notification on the bucket that calls a Lambda function each time there is a new PUT to that bucket.

The Lambda function would then do the work of looking at what's in the bucket and if it finds there are more than 20, delete the oldest.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html